# SoapUI 4.6.1 removes <value/> tag automatically (how to send null values?)

Tags: soapui

I am using SoapUI Pro 4.6.1. For one test case, I am firing a Soap Request in which I have the following block:

```
 [...]
 <property name="xyz">
   <value/>
 </property>
 [...]
```

This works fine the first time I run the testsuite. After it gets a response, SoapUI automatically removes the "<value/>" tag and leaves only whitespace there. There are no other changes made to the rest of the request.

I need that <value/> tag to be present else I get an error in the response. Does anyone know how this can be fixed? Is there some setting of SoapUI which needs to be set?

PS: I have tried suggestion [here](http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-send-null-values-in-soapui-requests/), but it did not work. I got an error saying - The prefix "value" for attribute "value:nil" associated with an element type "value" is not bound.

Also, property "Remove empty content" is **false** for the request. If I make it true, for a valid request I get an error for response. I think it is because it is expecting that the tag will be passed, even if it is with *null* value.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this have anything to do with `groovy`?

Comment: Actually I was using a Groovy script to populate Properties sheet, and was referring to values in the Soap Request from there. Wasn't sure if maybe the linkage caused the issue, so had tagged with Groovy. Apologies for the wrong tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case, used SOAP UI 4.5.2 and it doesn't happen there

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Keeping this question open for a little while more. If I can't find any other way around this, would move back to v.4.5. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me. I used SoapUI Pro 4.5.2, and I got the same issue after one run. Sorry for the late update, forgot that I hadn't posted back on this.